# Drupal 7 cache & css compression affects sub-domains

Tags: css, caching, drupal, drupal-7

There is an issue with caching on my website. I used standard in-build cache and css&js compression previously, but now I had to turn it off. Turns out, all js&css code still minified. What's more - it affects sub-domain folders (my host is bluehost) so all sub-domain are also have same problem with scripts.
It's really weird issue. I tried to clear all `cache_` tables from Drupal database, as well as everything related to cache from /sites/ folder. Still no result.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have used advagg or minify module for that. If so - you need disable them in order to get rid of minification.

I would also recommend to inspect the current css files in browser and check what is the path to it. Doing that you would get better understanding what is going on here.

After disabling minification options on System/Development/Performance page in the actual html source on a page it should change from

into a list of 
@import url("http://domain.name/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.css?nlpz6z");

Comment: Valera, I'm talking about Administration » Configuration » Development » Performance section. You CAN enable minifying of scripts here. Also we're not using advagg module and know how to check paths for css - they're ok.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. This make sense to me now. What is happening with css file names though when you disable this options? In a page it should change from
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.name/sites/default/files/css/css_Ag5s37c2rZPcDhB6PTYjBRiFA4V1AGSRh5k1FG8KTa4.css" media="all" />
into set of 
@import url("http://domain.name/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.css?nlpz6z");
What is happening with your page?

Comment: right, this is how it works right now. Each path has a "?nmlgv2" param at the end. However, even without this parameter all files are minified when I open them in browser. But when I look via ftp - they're not compressed. That's the weirdest part.

Comment: Really-really weird. Are you sure that you have cleared the cache. Can you reveal the link to the live website, please?